# can't not get heart rate from jawbone up3 api

Tags: php, api, heartbeat, jawbone

I am trying to get heart rate data with XML parse in PHP.

My personal information, "Moves" and "Sleeps" can be GET without any problem.
However, I can't get heart rate data that there is a 401 warning there:
Moves are available as

`$url = "https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/moves?start_time=1383289200 "`

However, heart rate is not available while I use url as follows:
`https://jawbone.com/nudge/api/v.1.1/users/@me/heartrates`

Is there anyone could help?

Comment: Could you provide some attempts?

Comment: what do you mean my attempts? by "curl" or something? is there any easy way to check where the endpoints is still alive for service?

Comment: The endpoint is still alive. If you're getting a 401 that means your app does not have permission to retrieve that data. Did you include heartrate_read in your OAuth scopes?

Comment: To Ray, thank you for your advice. After adding $scopes[] = "heartrate_read", the heart rate is available. However, the result is an average value of per day. I need data in every short interval such as 1 minute~5 minute. Is  there anyway to do that?

Comment: By the way, I found the heart rate info have been default set to be "private" in UP3, that I cannot share the heart rate data into another app.

Comment: Hi @Iruka_huang, the API only supports one heartrate reading per day. At this time, there is no way to get any more granular.

Comment: Thanks, RAY. It helps to get the answer. If heart rate in every minutes is available, there analysis must be interesting! What a pity.